# Specific section format

Tags: sectioning, formatting, rules, titlesec

I'd like to use `titlesec` to typeset a section header that would look like this:

> --------- Name of Section ------------

(the ---- would be a rule, and the entire section header would be centered)

I've looked at the `titlesec` documentation, but I'm a little confused as to how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do something along these lines; the `\varhrulefill` command is a variant of `\hrulefill`, but lifting the line above the baseline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand*\varhrulefill{%
  \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.6ex depth -0.5ex\hfill\kern0pt}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{\varhrulefill\enspace#1\enspace\varhrulefill}

\begin{document}

\section{A Test Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case of titles spanning more than one line, a little more work needs to be done: now the tile is placed inside a `\parbox` with centered contents; the width of the `\parbox` is calculated as the minimum between the length of the title and `0.7\textwidth` (this value can be changed), and then the `\parbox` is placed in the center with the two surrounding rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\Titlewd
\newlength\TitleBox

\newcommand*\varhrulefill{%
  \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.6ex depth -0.5ex\hfill\kern0pt}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{%
  \settowidth\Titlewd{\Large\bfseries#1}%
  \setlength\TitleBox{\minof{\Titlewd}{.7\textwidth}}%
  \varhrulefill\enspace\parbox{\TitleBox}{\centering #1}\enspace\varhrulefill}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{4.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\section{A Test Section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{A Test Section with a long title spanning more than one line}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that even though the section number is not included in the title (in the document body), it still will appear in an eventual table of contents; to remove the section number from the ToC, the following lines can be added to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{section}
  [0em]{\bfseries}{}{}
  {\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{10pt}]
```

Comment: Amazing. Just amazing :)