# Fancy style section titles for a resume

Tags: sectioning, rules

I'm wondering if exists a way in LaTeX to create a section title style (for a resume) like this:

```
--------------------Education-------------------
```

There's for sure a wrong way, simply adding - sign but requires to write manually all characters... in that case why even using LaTeX? :)

What about `\hline` `\line` or something similar?

Comment: Some time ago I gave an answer to this, allowing for multiple line titles, using the titlesec package: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57258/3954.

Answer (score 5):

A nice exercise in low level TeX commands. :)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

%%% this is the important code
\newcommand{\myresumesection}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}
  \noindent\myresumetitle{#1}\par
  \addvspace{\medskipamount}
}
\newcommand{\myresumetitle}[1]{%
  \makebox[\textwidth][s]{\large\bfseries
    \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr .5ex + 0.2pt\relax
                   depth -\dimexpr .5ex - 0.2pt\relax\hfill
    \ #1\ 
    \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr .5ex + 0.2pt\relax
                   depth -\dimexpr .5ex - 0.2pt\relax\hfill
  }%
}
%%% end of the important code

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\myresumesection{Education}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The mysterious instructions are:

1. Make sure we are at the start of a paragraph
2. Add some vertical space
3. Print the title in a box
4. End the line
5. Add some vertical space

Now the *more mysterious* instructions

1. The box is as wide as the lines
2. Its content must be stretched to fill, in `\large` size and boldface type
3. Print a rule at mid height of the letters without ascenders or descenders (`1ex` is precisely the height of an "x"); the rule is actually slightly higher, and its depth is *negative*, so the net effect is a rule 0.4pt thick
4. Print the title surrounded by spaces
5. Print another rule to fill

[image]

In order to avoid a page break just after the title, change the first definition into

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myresumesection}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}
  \noindent\myresumetitle{#1}\par
  \nobreak\vskip\medskipamount\@afterheading
}
\makeatother
```

(`\@afterheading` is the magic trick that LaTeX uses for section titles)

Answer (score 4):

The [`xhfill` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xhfill) provides these extensible rules. And, since this is for a resume, it would most likely be overkill to use `\section`s. Here's a minimal example showing the use of `xhfill` via `\mytitle[<thickness>]{<title>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{xhfill}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xhfill
\newcommand*{\mytitle}[2][.4pt]{%
  \bigskip\noindent\leavevmode\xrfill{#1}~{\bfseries\large#2}~\xrfill{#1}\mbox{}\nobreak\par
}
\begin{document}
\mytitle{Education}
\lipsum[1]
\mytitle{Professional background}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}​
```

Default for `<thickness>` is `.4pt`.